# Error al importar CSV a Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-excel

Estoy tratando de importar un archivo CSV en Laravel 8 utilizando la librería Excel. Sigo los pasos de la documentación pero a la hora de la importación me genera un error y sinceramente no sé por donde tirar.

He creado la clase import:

```
class EmployeesImport implements ToModel, WithStartRow, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ';',
            'input_encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'enclosure'     => ''
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        /* dd($row); */
        return new Employee(
            [
                'cod_employee'      => ['cod_employee'],
                'sex'               => ['sex'],
                'age'               => ['age'],
                'birth_date'        => ['birth_date'],
                'educational_level' => ['educational_level'],
                'num_children'      => ['num_children']
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

La ruta:

```
Route::post(
    'admin/employees/import', [EmployeesController::class, 'importEmployees']
)->name('import-employee');
```

El controlador:

```
public function importEmployees(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate(
            [
                'file' => 'required',
            ]
        );
  
        Excel::import(new EmployeesImport, request()->file('file'));
        return redirect()->back()->with(
            'success', 'Datos importados correctamente.'
        );    
    }
```

Y la vista:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('import-employee')}}" id="formImportFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Importar</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-round waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar Operación</button>
</form>
```

Sin embargo a la hora de realizar la importación me lanza el siguiente error:

> TypeError
> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\laragon\www\AppIgualdad\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 886

¿Alguién me puede decir que está generando el error?

Answer (score 0):

Disculpar. Ya he detectado el error. No había incluido el objeto $row en los encabezados.

```
return new Employee(
    [
        'cod_employee'      => $row['cod_employee'],
        'sex'               => $row['sex'],
        'age'               => $row['age'],
        'birth_date'        => $row['birth_date'],
        'educational_level' => $row['educational_level'],
        'num_children'      => $row['num_children'],
        'client_id'         => $row['client_id']
    ]
);
```

Gracias